# Undefined reference to static constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code snippet:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Foo {
   static constexpr std::array<char, N> arr{{0}};
   static const char *data() { return &arr[0]; }
};

template<>
constexpr std::array<char, 5> Foo<5>::arr;

int main()
{
   std::cout << Foo<5>::data() << std::endl;
}
```

with gcc 5.2 I got undefined reference to `Foo<5ul>::arr`, while clang 3.7 gives a compile time error:

> declaration of constexpr static data member 'arr' requires an initializer

What is wrong, and how should `static constexpr` be defined outside class declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The out-of-line definiton is the same as for other static (non integral) members,  minus the initialization:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N> Foo<N>::arr;
```

Like other static members, this goes in a header - like the class template itself.

Comment: But where this should go? if it is in header file, will I got multiply definition if include into several files? If it is in c++ file, then how compiler handle different specilizations?

Comment: Put it in the header. Since it is a template definition, it has to work.