# Undefined reference to constexpr with clang

Tags: c++

The following code compiles fine on GCC, but not on Clang, why? If I understood correctly static constexpr expressions must be defined out-of-line, which is what I did, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Bar;

template <>
struct Bar<Foo> {
    static constexpr char const * foo[] = { "foo" };
};

constexpr char const * Bar<Foo>::foo[];

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << Bar<Foo>::foo[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Yields the following:

```
❯ [DESKTOP-NJURELH?] /tmp ❯ clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 z.cc

/tmp/z-e6820c.o: In function `main':
z.cc:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `Bar<Foo>::foo'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found a possibly related question here: [Undefined reference to static constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322819/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr), but the answer suggests to use a generic definition which is not what I can do (`Bar<Foo>` must be a specialization, the template itself has no definition).

Comment: seems to work fine [with clang on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68b7a2e1a5b6325b)

Comment: Hm, the version I have is `clang version 5.0.0-svn312333-1~exp1 (branches/release_50)`. This issue also appears on the latest Android NDK beta release.

Comment: Seems to be a Clang regression: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34332